# Equivalent method for Java class HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(<any string>); in Salesforce

Tags: apex, java

I am trying to find equivalent Salesforce class for the following code. `HttpEntity` is a Java class.

```
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(msg);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: Rest callouts can be used in Apex. Refer this trailhead module- [Apex REST Callouts](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts). Equivalent is [HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm)

Comment: Instead of asking for exact matching class (many times, it is not possible), explain what you are trying to achieve. Folks may point to way of doing this in Salesforce way.